# CP violation in B meson system through mixing

Tags: particle-physics, cp-violation

Mathematically, $\left|\Gamma_{12}\right|<<\left|M_{12}\right|$ implies $\left|q/p\right|=1$,i.e there is no CP violation due to mixing. Please explain why it happens beyond this mathematical reason.

Comment: It might help you get more responses if you could remind us non-beauty people what you mean by $\Gamma,M,q,p$